# Add form tab to all the entities in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

My requirement is to add a Tab inside the form(not a ribbon tab) on create of custom configuration record. The functionality is like this:

A custom config entity has a field called 'Entity Name'. On creation of this config record I need to add one form Tab to an entity specified in 'Entity Name' field in this config record. Here my idea is to add this tab to all the entities, and Hide/Show this tab by querying the config records with current entity name. So, is there any way to add tab to all the entities in one shot? (OR/AND) Can we configure to add one default tab to all newly creating entities like 'Notes' tab?

If I'm wrong, it would be great if any suggestions from your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://charanmandya.blogspot.in/2012/12/addremove-tab-in-entity-form-using-plug.html) is the way to add/remove tab on create/delete of config record through plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box way of doing this. My recommendation would be to keep it simple and do it manually.

Comment: Yeah. But whenever we create new entities we have to add it manually again.

Comment: How often are you creating new entities?!